# Does total coordinate ring completely determines a variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose we are given with a finitely generated total coordinate ring $R(X)$ of an algebraic variety $X$ over a field $k$. It is given by $\bigoplus_{D \in Cl(X)}H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(D))$. Generally this ring is only birational invariant of X: grading gives an action of $G:=Spec \ k [Cl(X)]$ on $Spec(R(X))$ and different choices of divisor classes give different irrelevant ideals $J_{irr}(D)$ in $R(X)$ and, therefore, quotient spaces $Spec(R(X))\setminus Z(J_{irr}(D))//G$.

My question is what restrictions should we apply to $X$ that all the quotients are isomorphic for any choice of divisor class? Is it true, for example, for toric varieties, that $R(X)$ completely determines variety up to isomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with a nitpick: one shouldn't say that this ring is a "birational invariant". For example, the ring is graded by Pic, but blowing up a point (which is birational, of course) increases the rank of Pic by 1.

What is true is that if $f: X \dashrightarrow Y$ is a *small $\mathbf Q$-factorial modification* (meaning that both varieties are $\mathbf Q$-factorial and $f$ is an isomorphism in codimension 1) then $R(X)$ is unchanged.

So to answer your question, we need conditions on $X$ so that no nontrivial such $X$ exist. It is not hard to see that being toric is not enough: for example, the blowup of $\mathbf P^3$ in 2 points is toric, but the line through the two points can be flopped, giving a small $\mathbf Q$-factorial modification.

On the other hand, if $X$ has Picard number 1, or is a homogeneous variety, then this is true. I can't think of any other good sufficient conditions at the moment.